# ASP .NET custom control validation is not working in Firefox or Chrome?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, validation, custom-controls

I use the date picker control from [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21930/Date-Picker-User-Control). here is the generated code for a DatePickerControl with ID="DatePicker1"
and a required field validator with ID="dateValid1"

```
<span id="DatePicker1" style="display:inline-block;">
    <table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" style="border-width:0px;border-style:None;border-collapse:collapse;white-space:nowrap;">
        <tr>
             <td valign="middle" style="border-style:none;border-width:0px;height:30px;">
                 <input name="DatePicker1$txt" type="text" id="DatePicker1_txt" OnKeyPress="return checkAllowedKey(event);" ReadOnly="true" style="width:70px;" />&nbsp
             </td>
             <td style="height:30px;"><img id="DatePicker1_img" onclick="javascript:return popUpCalendar(this, document.getElementById(&#39;DatePicker1_txt&#39;), &#39;M/d/yyyy&#39;, 1, false);" src="/WebResource.axd?d=ckpr7cUtwvCqFzFtoOMMl-4meGGqq3nc2D5C6-dKgqdMrj98KyPSR4rWmz3ep5RWWG3PiCx0mH7RhNYzT4Y5-Ms5Jyq9icgD32i9a4keUnHT0RDYjrVVQCgudwPoIHymrp3dls954_LcWKuDlvPu4g2&amp;t=635423491947401645" />
             </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</span>

<span id="dateValid1" style="color:Red;display:none;">*required</span>
```

and the javascript code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
//<![CDATA[
var dateValid1 = document.all ? document.all["dateValid1"] : document.getElementById("dateValid1");
dateValid1.controltovalidate = "DatePicker1";
dateValid1.errormessage = "*required";
dateValid1.display = "Dynamic";
dateValid1.evaluationfunction = "RequiredFieldValidatorEvaluateIsValid";
dateValid1.initialvalue = "";
//]]>
</script>
```

the problem is that the validator is always not valid in Chrome and Firefox, but it works fine in IE.

Comment: can I see checkAllowedKey function?

Comment: download the source code from this link http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21930/Date-Picker-User-Control

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I downloaded the source code and changed the generated html code such that it does not use tables. The validation worked after this fix. the generated code for the example in this question will be

```
<span id="DatePicker1" style="display:inline-block;">
   <input name="DatePicker1$txt" type="text" id="DatePicker1_txt" OnKeyPress="return checkAllowedKey(event);" ReadOnly="true" style="width:70px;" />
   <img id="DatePicker1_img" onclick="javascript:return popUpCalendar(this, document.getElementById(&#39;DatePicker1_txt&#39;), &#39;M/d/yyyy&#39;, 1, false);" src="/WebResource.axd?d=ckpr7cUtwvCqFzFtoOMMl-4meGGqq3nc2D5C6-dKgqdMrj98KyPSR4rWmz3ep5RWWG3PiCx0mH7RhNYzT4Y5-Ms5Jyq9icgD32i9a4keUnHT0RDYjrVVQCgudwPoIHymrp3dls954_LcWKuDlvPu4g2&amp;t=635423491947401645" />
</span>
```

see [this link](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/21930/Date-Picker-User-Control) for the project my fix would be in the alternatives if it got accepted